# Beamer: strikeout with onslide produces "perhaps a missing \item"

Tags: beamer, errors, itemize, strikeout

Following the recommendation in [In beamer, how to strike through an item after displaying](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35767/46529), I wrote this:

```
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\renewcommand{\ULthickness}{1pt}

\newcommand{\myonly}[3]{\only<+>{\item #1#2}\only<+->{\item #3{#1}#2}}
\newcommand{\strike}[1]{\myonly{#1}{?}{\sout}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{test}
Well...

\onslide<+->  %%% THIS IS THE PROBLEM!

So...

\begin{itemize}
  \strike{foo}
  \strike{bar}
  \strike{baz}
  \myonly{zot}{!}{\emph}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces somewhat correct output *except*

1. There is an error `LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`.
2. The first `\onslide` is ignored: both `well` and `so` appear on the 1st slide.

Removing the 1st `\onslide<+->` does *not* change the output but removes the error message.

Adding `\item` before the 1st `\strike` also removes the error message.

What I want is that `so` should appear on the 2nd slide and, obviously, I do not want the error message.

PS. Adding option `handout` removes the error message, of course.

Comment: Try changing `\onslide<+->` to `\onslide<.->`.

Comment: @manooooh: thanks, the error is gone, but `so` is still on the 1st slide. What is the difference between `.` and `+`?

Comment: Hm so try this: `\onslide<.(2)->{So...}`. For `.` see this: [The beamer slide overlay concept](https://www.texdev.net/2014/01/17/the-beamer-slide-overlay-concept/#:~:text=Repeating,the).

Comment: @manooooh Actually, I have a lot of other stuff before `Well`, so I am extremely reluctant to use explicit slide numbers like `2`. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @manooooh: your suggestion does not work, alas: `foo` appears crossed out immediately